# Why should I not add Fragments to the activity layout XML file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

Edit: source : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html last parargraph says :

> Note: When you add a fragment to an activity layout by defining the
>   fragment in the layout XML file, you cannot remove the fragment at
>   runtime. If you plan to swap your fragments in and out during user
>   interaction, you must add the fragment to the activity when the
>   activity first starts, as shown in the next lesson.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please quote your sources and give us their exact link if you want us to chime in. The official documentation does say you can use fragments in xml. And I do not know where they it's not recommended.

Comment: In my mind,  define the fragment in individual xml(eg. fragment.xml) is better. fragment should be flexiable to switch.

Comment: added source so it's more clear.

Comment: sou you inflate the fragment everytime your activity creates. and then you remove it and add another one. when you could just add the one you need to a container frame layout right away in code...

Answer (score 1):

You can use fragments in two ways ,

1. Static Fragments

Here you can define the fragment in whatever the layout file you need. Only thing is, that defined fragment can not be change at the run time. So, re-usability will be  issue here, you cant take the advantage of the re-usability of fragments in this case.

2. Dynamic Fragments

Here you can define a place holder(frame layout etc) on your layout and you can add/replace whatever the fragment you expect at any time while your activity is running. This ensure the re-usability.

Also you can use backStack if back navigation is required.

So, it depend on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If the fragments are defined in Xml you won't be able to change them at runtime; in that case I'd suggest using an `<include layout="@layout/my_inner_layout"/>` tag, that is not only  better performance-wise as it is easier to use (you can access the views defined in my_inner_layout.xml using `findViewById()` method from the host activity).

Comment: Yes you are able to change them at runtime if they are defined in the activity layout. That's incorrect.

Comment: my bad I was using hide/Show instead of add/remove